# Outlook: count sent based on signature

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

We send emails from a shared outlook address
And now I want to find out how many emails I answer everyday because my boss wants to give me more work but I want to get an idea of how I actually compared to my colleagues before I agree on taking more work

Wondering if it's possible to count how many sent emails we send everyday and then filter that based on our signatures

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best and the most easiest way is to handle the [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event which is fired when an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 
 
 
 
Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
 
 Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 
 
End Sub 
 
 
 
Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
 
 Dim prompt As String 
 
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
 
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
 
 Cancel = True 
 
 End If 
 
End Sub
```

So, each time the `ItemSend` event is fired we can increase the counter.

Another possible solution is to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods for getting the number of items that contain specific keywords in the message body. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Get unread Outlook e-mail items from the Inbox folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/27/outlook-get-unread-items/)

Answer (score 0):

If the signature includes something unique to the user, just search the Sent Items folder for a match in the `Body` property using `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.